Azure Managed Instance - how to do a cross-database service broker certificate
I have migrated processes from on-prem to Managed Instance. In one case I have an activated stored procedure (service broker) that does a cross-database query. I have no idea how this worked beforehand - I suspect the database was marked TRUSTWORTHY (I have the backup but no idea how to tell, and restoring the DB removes that). I'd rather do it properly.
In the past for other service broker items, I've read through and done module signing as per https://rusanu.com/2006/03/07/call-a-procedure-in-another-database-from-an-activated-procedure/ .
But I'm unsure how you do this on Managed Instance - everything I can find about exporting the certificate to file etc, obviously doesn't work, and all the code I've found online about certificates is for TDE which has very specific powershell commands meant for the TDE cert.
I'm stuck. All help appreciated.

To allow another instance to send messages using Service Broker transport security, create a user for the instance and install its certificate in Azure SQL Managed Instance. You can use PowerShell to upload the certificate, following steps outlined in relevant documentation for certificate-based access and migration.
